# Angular 4 Increased Web App Size

Tags: angular

I've migrated my current Angular 2 Web App to Angular 4 but didn't see any positive changes in App size (dist folder size). Instead Angular 2 was 17.8MB and Angular 4 version of the App turns out to be 18MB.

Previous version : 2.4.9 17.8MB

Current Version: 4.0.1 18MB

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: The size improvements between the two versions occurred in reduction of AoT template size.  Do you use AoT compilation?

Comment: @DavidL Yes I have tried using AoT with webpack. Not much of a difference. Now the size turns out to be 17.7MB.